# Numpy compare two arrays take for each entry the smaller one

Tags: python, numpy

I have two Arrays (which are **very** big), which have the same dimensions. In one of the both Arrays (in my code it's called "minMap") i want to save the smaller value of those both arrays

My current code looks like this:

```
        for y in range(loadedMap.shape[1]):
            for x in range(loadedMap.shape[0]):
                if loadedMap[x][y] < minMap[x][y]:
                    minMap[x][y] = loadedMap[x][y]
```

It's working but im pretty sure it's a dumb solution, because I haven't used any numpy functionality. Maybe a solution with vectorization is faster? I didn't know how to do that :/

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: looks good to me

Answer (score 2):

There is a function [np.minimum()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) which does exactly what you want:

```
# a and b are 2 arrays with same shape
c = np.minimum(a, b)
# c will contain minimum values from a and b
```